# URL Redirect and convert / (Slash) and . (Dot) to - (Hyphen)

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

We want to redirect the WordPress site URL from `/` (slash) to `-` (Hyphen) and `.htm` to `-htm`.

We are importing some custom URL structure into our WordPress wp_post table.

Existing post_name format is not supported in WordPress.

Example:

This is our existing URL format:

```
https://www.example.com/latest-news/my-url-string/click123.htm
```

Now we would like to convert this URL like this:

```
https://www.example.com/latest-news/my-url-string-click123-htm
```

So previously indexed URLs can redirect to this new format.

Comment: What have you tried? Which parts of the URL-path are variable and which are fixed? Is `/latest-news/` fixed? Or is the entire URL-path variable?

Answer (score 0):

From your example I assume the following:

- there is just one slash to replace before the last path segment.
- there is just one `.htm` to replace (with `-htm`) at the end of the URL-path.
- `/lastest-news/` is fixed at the start of the URL-path
- `my-url-string` is variable, but is a single path segment.
- `/click123` is variable (essentially the file basename before `.htm`) but does not itself contain a dot.

In which case you can use the following at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller. ie. Before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section:

```
# Redirect custom URL structure
RewriteRule ^(latest-news/[^/]+)/([\w-]+)\.htm$ /$1-$2-htm [R=302,L]
```

The above would redirect URLs of the form:

```
/latest-news/<path-segment>/<file>.htm
```

to

```
/latest-news/<path-segment>-<file>-htm
```

The `$1` and `$2` backreferences contain parts of the URL captured from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

- `$1` contains `latest-news/<page-segment>`
- `$2` contains `<file>`.

There is no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine On` directive, since this already occurs later in the WordPress section.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended in order to avoid potential caching issues.